# Set multiple select boxes on a predefined array base (AlpineJS)

Tags: alpine.js

I want to create a multiple filter list with select-boxes and it already worked for creating the count of selections. By loading the page, some selectedEvents can be predefined (it is set through GET parameter + PHP). I already searched a lot in the web but didn't find any similar case with AlpineJS, how to set these predefined values as "selected".

In my example below, I want that the first  has selected the event with id 1000 and the 2nd  has selected the event with id 1002. The 3rd  will have no selection in this case.

Any ideas or recommendations? :)

```
<section class="panel" x-data='{
        events: [
                { id: "1000", name: "My 1st cool event" },
                { id: "1001", name: "My 2nd cool event" },
                { id: "1002", name: "Just a better event" },
        ],
        selectedEvents: [ 1000, 1002 ],
        countFilter: 3
    }
'>
<template x-for="_ in Array.from({ length: countFilter })">
                <select name="event_id[]" required>
                    <option value="">Please choose</option>
                    <template x-for="event in events" :key="event.id">
                        <option :value="event.id" x-text="event.name"></option>
                    </template>
                </select><br>
            </template>
<button type="button" @click="countFilter++">Add selection</button>
            <button type="button" @click="countFilter--" x-show="countFilter > 1">Remove selection</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select default option dynamically by binding the `selected` attribute of the options, e.g. `:selected="checkSelect(index, event.id)"`. Where the `checkSelect` is the function checking whether the actual `select` element has a provided default option or not. If a default value is present and the current option's value is equal to the default option, then it returns `true` so the current option will receive a `selected` attribute.

The complete example:

```
<section class="panel" x-data='{
        events: [
                { id: "1000", name: "My 1st cool event" },
                { id: "1001", name: "My 2nd cool event" },
                { id: "1002", name: "Just a better event" },
        ],
        selectedEvents: [ 1000, 1002 ],
        countFilter: 3,
        checkSelect(select_index, option_id) {
            return option_id == this.selectedEvents[select_index]
        },
    }
'>
<template x-for="(_, index) in Array.from({ length: countFilter })">
    <select name="event_id[]" required class="block">
    <option value="">Please choose</option>
    <template x-for="event in events" :key="event.id">
        <option :value="event.id" x-text="event.name" :selected="checkSelect(index, event.id)"></option>
    </template>
    </select>
</template>
<button type="button" @click="countFilter++">Add selection</button>
<button type="button" @click="countFilter--" x-show="countFilter > 1">Remove selection</button>
</section>
```

Note that we have also added an `index` variable to the first loop, so we can track the current select element in the loop (we use it as the first argument of `checkSelect` function).